# How to extract dates from a given string in Java

Tags: java, regex, date

For example, in:

```
"ABC 1 January 2014"
  "$%^DA sfad AD Friday 18 April 2014"
  "GOOD Day Tuesday 13 May 2014"
```

I want get the date strings from them, like

```
"1 January 2014"
  "18 April 2014"
  "13 May 2014"
```

If the prefix strings are already known, is it possible use regex to achieve it? If so how to do that?

Comment: if you want to test out some regex, you can use [this online editor](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). it has worked pretty well for me in the past

Answer (score 2):

If your strings are really that simple you can use

```
"\\b\\d{1,2}\\s+(January|February|March...etc)\\s+\\d{4}\\b"
```

Explanation:

```
\\b            # word boundary
\\d{1,2}       # one or two digits
\\s+           # some whitespace
(January etc)  # all months, spelled out, delimited by |
\\s+           # more whitespace
\\d{4}         # exactly 4 digits
\\b            # word boundary
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a good regular expression to extract that information. Take a look  on the following links:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html